# Problem on Spring... Error 404, unmapped HTML page. How to proceed?

Tags: java, spring, web

The HTML page does not load (error 404), even though the server is working and starting normally. I've tried with RequestMapping("/") as well. Here is the code, the project structure image and the terminal image after spring initialization

project structure: [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN0sP.png)

indexController.java:

```
package com.anotherversion.maven.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class indexController {
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Index page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Olá mundo com spring boot</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.anotherversion</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>maven</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

terminal: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kng0c.png)

new terminal photo: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egtoi.png)

I tried showing a simple html page with spring boot. I believe the page was not properly mapped

Comment: A 404 shows that the process is running on the port but little more. Looks like you are using Thymeleaf. Please add pom.xml and application.properties. Also, add a method that returns a ResponseEntity<String> and see if that 404s.

Comment: done! The pom.xml and the photo of the new terminal are there. The web browse displayed "Page not found". I did not download the thymeleaf dependencys

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues - the fact that a controller method that returns a ResponsEntity gave a 404 indicates that basic functions are failing.

Change the spring boot starter parent to 3.0.4.

Add the following dependency to get Thymeleaf to work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Add the main @SpringbootApplication class to the question.

Comment: thank you so much, it worked! I just didnt understand why it wasnt working before